# Why does transistor output resistance matter less in discrete circuit applications?

Tags: analog

In their *Microelectronic Circuits*, Sedra and Smith emphasize over and over that in discrete circuit (DC) applications it is often very reasonable to ignore \$r_0\$, the transistor output resistance (due to CLM in MOSFETs and the Early effect in BJTs), whereas this is not appropriate in ICs. Why is this?

In MOSFETs I sort of have an answer, I think. Is the answer as simple as that discrete-circuit transistors are usually much larger than their IC counterparts so that (since \$r_0\$ scales with \$L\$ in MOSFETs, it is very large (and thus ignorable) in such cases? I can't think of an analogous argument for BJTs since the base width \$W_B\$ is independent of aspect ratio in any fabrication process I'm familiar with, so I'm not sure why IC and DC BJTs would be so different. Is there perhaps some bigger reason that I'm missing?

Comment: Have you looked to see if they ever give a reason?

Comment: EE18, constant current biasing throughout the IC.

Comment: @TimWescott I suppose it could be later on in the book, but it's been 100 pages or so since the first mention and nothing.

Comment: Agreed that this surely matters from a load transistor perspective, but also it appears to be relevant for the amplifying transistors too! That's why I'm not sure I'm convinced it's just that but I could well be wrong @periblepsis

Comment: @EE18 Think about what it means for the collector to be working against a current source/sink vs working against a discrete resistor (and load) as the collector load in a discrete circuit. Add in VA. Now, in the IC case does VA dominate the gain calc or the finite impedance of the current source/sink? In the discrete case, does VA dominate the gain calc? Or the collector resistor and driven load?

Comment: To your point and that of Sedra and Smith, the answer is that \$V_A\$ of the amplifying transistor matters only in the IC case but I'm afraid I can't see (rigorously) why @periblepsis

Comment: @EE18 We'll leave it there, then.